# How to send array into API call to set a list of objects - angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I have this:

In my API:

```
router.post('/setsuggestions', auth, function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.challengessuggestions){
    return res.status(400).json({message: challengessuggestions});
  }

  var query = { username: req.body.username };
  User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { challengessuggestions: req.body.challengessuggestions }, callback = function(){
    //console.log("Ja");
  });
  res.json(200);

});
```

challengessuggestions is a list of Challenges.

I use this code in my angular app:

```
auth.setsuggestions = function(user, suggestions){
            console.log(suggestions);
            return{
                getValue: function(){
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/setsuggestions',
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        transformRequest: function(obj) {
                            var str = [];
                            for(var p in obj)
                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                            return str.join("&");
                        },
                        data : {username: user, challengessuggestions: suggestions}
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        //$route.reload();
                        //$window.location.reload(true)
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Console.log(suggestions) gives me:

[image: Console output of suggestions]

This doesn't set anything in my database.

When I use postman, I get a 200 answer that the API call succeeded, but nothing is set in the database. This is the postman config:

[image: Postman config]

How can I set the list of challenges (objects) properly?

Comment: Do you get success or error response from angularjs $http request? Try add anonymous error function in then. `.then(function (success) {}, function (error) { console.log(error) }`

Comment: Firstly, don't you want to send the response after the 'findOneAndUpdate' call?  Move 'res.json(200);' into the 'findOneAndUpdate' function callback body.

Comment: Ok it succeeded to set 1 challenge, but how do I set an array of challenges? I used this in postman: 563141ab8c5ba50300f2b4f5

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a data model like Mongoose, if you are using MongoDB, to handle your interactions with your database.

Comment: That's probably where you should start

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push

you can modify

```
    { challengessuggestions: req.body.challengessuggestions } to
    { challengessuggestions: {$push: req.body.challengessuggestions}
```

The $push operator appends a specified value to an array

if you're receiving an array from the request body then setting the key to that value should be sufficient.

also is the model you're applying this to contain challengesuggestions as an array of something?